# Infinite componentDidUpdate() calls with react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am new to `react-router` and right now I have following routes in my app:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={MainLayout}>
        <Route path="/v/:username/:reponame/:page/:perPage" component={Results} />
    </Route>
</Router>
```

As you can see, there's a MainLayout component that includes an `<input type="text">` which is used to connect to Github API and retrieve list of issues for a certain repo.

Then the `Results` component steps in. Here's the code for it's `componentDidMount()`:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const {
        username,
        reponame,
        page,
        perPage
    } = this.props.params;
    this.sendRequest(username, reponame, page, perPage);
}
```

`sendRequests` essentially contains the ajax query for fetching the output data, after which it's being set into the component's state:

```
    this.state = {
        data: [], // here
        lastPage: -1,
        errorMessage: ''
    }
```

Now this works pretty well till the very moment when one wants to change the value of an `input`.

As I see, the `Result` component doesn't unmount. Instead, it invokes `componentWillReceiveProps()` and updates the existing component. AFAIK it is safe to perform side calls in `componentDidUpdate()` so I just copied the code above from `componentDidMount()` and pasted it in there. This way, though (and it is absolutely reasonable) `componentDidMount()` is being invoked over and over again.

The only workaround I came up with at the moment is comparing old and new data in the `sendRequest()` itself and invoke `setState()` inside of it only if it differs via `deep-equal` package, so it looks like this:

```
    if (!equal(res, this.state.data)) {
        this.setState({
          ...this.state,
          data: res,
          lastPage
        });
    }
```

Is this considered to be an ok pattern or there is a better way to solve this issue?

Comment: you could make a string comparison if you stringify both objects, this should be faster. But if you just compare data in the state then it would be enought to call `this.setState({ data: res })`

Answer (score 1):

You should not use setState inside the cDM lifecycle. as it might trigger re-render, which will cause your infinite loop.

> Updating the state after a component mount will trigger a second render() call and can lead to property/layout thrashing.
>
> https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-did-mount-set-state.md